# Rails 3 image translations with i18n and tolk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

I have implemented tolk engine by dhh to add translations and then create .yml files from it. It works well for text.

Now what I want is same behavior over images.

I create follwing structure in my en.yml file -

images:
     logo: "/images/en/logo.png"

and for hi

images:
     logo: "/images/hi/logo.png

and in my views, I have - 
   <%= t("images.logo") %>

This also works for showing different images depending on locale.

But I want to add these translations via tolk engine, so that I can directly upload images from there, and they will stored in respective folders. Also when yml files will be created, that will include structures like above.

Is there any tolk fork already doing this ? or people prefer different approach for image translations(replace as per locals) than this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not familiar with tolk, but what about using the i18n in the path of an `image_tag`

Something like:

`<%= image_tag("images/#{t("i18n")}/logo.png") %>`

Comment: I think it should be `"images/#{I18n.locale}/logo.png"`

Comment: The only issue is - if i use <%= t("images.logo") %> - it renders /images/en/logo.png if locale is not present(present means written in hi.yml file.) and this - images/hi/logo.png if present.
Seems i need to write some custom view helpers to handle this conditions. 
Thanks, this seems better solution, I will go with it.